# How to make a histogram of the counts of a categories in python

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

If I have a column that looks like this:

```
Sam
Alex
Amy
Amy
Enrique
Daniel
Daniel
Daniel
```

How can I convert it in python to a histogram showing the frequency of how many times a name is counted. In this case, my histogram should show there are three names with a count of 1 and then 1 name with a count of 2 and 1 name with a count of 3.
And get a plot like this:

[image: histogram]

Thanks !

Comment: I am unaware of a Python data structure "column".

Comment: So I mean column as in a column of a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to plot a simple histogram. Suppose you have a dataframe `df` and column you want to plot is `column`, you can do:

```py
import pandas as pd
df['column'].hist(bins=10, edgecolor='black')
```